# C# Decrypting a file

Tags: c#, drm, encryption

I am attempting to encrypt a file that will be deployed with an application I want to sell.  My question is if I encrypt the file and deploy the application will the end user be able to decrypt the file using .NET?

If so, what would be the best way to encrypt the file where my application will be the only application/code to decrypt the file?

Comment: You can obfuscate the file, but you can't encrypt it *securely*.

Comment: Standard .NET assemblies are easy to reverse engineering. See yourself, using for example [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx). If you load your app and will be able to locate an encryption/decryption code and password, means somebody, who wants, also will do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is DRM, and DRM doesn't work.  You have to give the end user the key (install it somewhere on their machine) or the app won't work.  If you give the end user the key, they can use it outside your app.

Comment: but the application will have the key to decrypt and/or read the encrypted file.

Comment: @Developer09, right, and if the key is on the user's machine, they can use it outside your app.

Comment: So what do you suggest?  I am basically trying to include this file for licensing and application setting based on the version they have purchased.

Comment: @Developer09, I suggest that you spend your time making a great app, and hire a lawyer to enforce the license when you can afford it.

Comment: So what's the purpose of the .NET encrypting framework when it can be easily decrypted?  Sounds kind of pointless!

Comment: @Developer09 What you're asking for is to do something on a user's machine and make it impossible for a determined debugger to see what you're doing. That's not what encryption is about. Encryption is about two parties sending messages that might be intercepted. You can't control what the parties do after they've been given the key to decrypt the message.

Comment: @Developer09 it's not pointless - it just not made for what you want (i.e. a DRM) but for *real* cryptographic usage. E.g. where you want data to be *secure* between two trusted points (e.g. Alice and Bob) and in case of DRM one of the points is **not** secure.

Comment: @ConradFrix I'm sorry if my understanding is totally off.  So you're saying that there is no way to encrypt a file and only my application can read that file?  if this is the case how do other software vendors provide a license file with their application with no problems so to speak???

Comment: @Developer09, they don't.  Search for [Microsoft DRM crack](https://www.google.com/search?q=Microsoft+DRM+crack), and then substitute in any other company.